# How many ways are there to arrange students and teachers in two lines under the given conditions?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $24$ children and $4$ teachers. There are $2$ pairs of twins within the 24 children.  We want to arrange everyone in two lines.  In each line, there will be $12$ children, their order of appearance (or just order) does not matter, but there will be $1$ pair of twins in each line, there will be $2$ teachers in each line, on the sides of the line, and their order DOES MATTER.  How many possibilities are for arrangement are there?

What I did is pick $10$ out $20$ children, without/ rep & without/ order * pick $1$ out of $2$ couples of twins without/ rep & without/ order, pick $2$ out of $4$ teachers WITH order and without rep, and pick $2$ out of $2$ with order and without rep.  This all leads to 
$$\frac{20!}{10!10!} \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2$$
The answer is $$\frac{20!}{10!10!}  \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2$$ 
Can someone explain whats wrong with my solution? thanks

Comment: Does the order of the two lines matter?

Comment: dosent say anything about that (i guess thats part of the question, to understand from context)
i'm also not sure about if it DIDNT matter, then will you divide everything by 2? 
as far as i remember you do not need to divide here because my answer already implies that you cant switch the groups
if it did matter you would just add another 2 to the answer right? and that wouldnt solve anything

Comment: Your calculation is correct unless the order of the lines does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the line containing a particular teacher.

There are  $\begin{pmatrix}20\\10\\\end{pmatrix}$ ways of choosing the children in this line and, for each of these choices, $\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\\end{pmatrix}$ ways of choosing the pair of twins and $\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\\end{pmatrix}$ ways of choosing the fellow teacher. The teachers can then be arranged in $2\times2$ ways giving the answer $$\begin{pmatrix}20\\10\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\\end{pmatrix}\times2\times2=\frac{20!}{10!10!}  \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2.$$

Comment: can you explain the teacher part? you have to choose a pair for each line, and arrange them
picking a pair is pick 2 of 4 which is 3*2, arrange them is 2, and the second pair arrange is another 2
how did you get to 1 of 3 if there are 4 teachers and 2 pairs?

Comment: For this question which is about splitting the people into two groups (forget the lines) it is best to start with teacher $A$, say, and then there are $3$ ways of pairing him with another teacher.

Comment: The only arranging is with respect to which teacher is on the left or right of their "line" which gives the 2 x 2.

Comment: yeah but you do get my calculation about splitting them right? why is it wrong? it should work.. grouping 2 pairs of teachers..?

Comment: Your answer is correct  if there are to be  two distinguishable lines, line $1$ and line $2$. However, the question seems to indicate that all that matters is splitting into two groups with a teacher on each side of each group.

Comment: so can you get to their answer using my math by any way? if the two lines are different, then my math is right, but if they are the same, then what about the math? should you divide everything by 2 because they are different?
if so, ive been told that by default those 2 groups are the same according to my calculations, and if they are different you have to add ANOTHER 2

Comment: You should divide by 2.

Comment: alright thank you very much